# Do single letters in R have a length of 2?

Tags: r

Again I'm confounded by my datacamp R tutorial. A video presentation tries to explain the  difference between vapply and sapply, and presents the following code and outputs:

```
first_and_last <-function(name) {
  name <- gsub(" ", "", name)
  letters <- strsplit(name, split = "")[[1]]
  return(c(first = min(letters), last = max(letters))))
}

sapply(cities, first_and_last)


New York Paris London Tokyo Rio de Janeiro Cape Town  
first   "e"  "a"   "d"    "k"   "a"            "a"  
last    "y"  "s"   "o"    "y"   "R"        "w"


vapply(cities, first_and_last, character(2))

New York Paris London Tokyo Rio de Janeiro Cape Town  
first   "e"  "a"   "d"    "k"   "a"            "a"  
last    "y"  "s"   "o"    "y"   "R"        "w"
```

---

As we can see the output is identical. I am told that's because the length of the character vector in the vapply function is set manually to 2 and if it was set to 1 we would encounter an error.

I'm not sure I understand, these are single letters so why would we need a character vector with length 2?

Comment: Because you are returning two elements `first` and `last`.  If you choose only one, then you can specify `character(1)`

Comment: try `str(first_and_last(cities[[1]]))` to see what the function returns from the first element ...

Comment: @akrun Yes, the OP should try `character(1)` or `character(3)`.

Comment: alternately, try `sapply(cities, first_and_last, simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `length(chr_vec)` (which returns how many strings are in the vector) and `nchar(chr_vec)` (which returns the number of characters in each string in the vector). If you're comfortable with python, then R's `length("abc")` is very different from py's `len("abc")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify the return shape in `vapply` (in your case a character vector of length 2), it needs to match the return type of the function you are calling (`first_and_last`).

It actually doesn't matter if they are single letters or very long words, what matters is that `first_and_last` is returning a character vector with two elements in it.

Comment: So Vapply then needs to use a vector with length 2  in an intermetidate step before converting it to an array, and it needs my permission even to use this intermediate step?

Comment: @Magnus - I think you misunderstand the reason return type must be specified.  From the help: *"vapply is similar to sapply, but has a pre-specified type of return value, so it can be safer (and sometimes faster) to use."*